# Modified double slit with interferometer

Tags: double-slit-experiment, interferometry

Imagine I do a setup as seen in the picture below:
burrowed concept from LIGO, the idea here is to use the gravitational force exerts by the heavy particle to bend the laser beams when passing through the slits, ideally if for instance a particle went in through slit 1 so the laser beam will recombined and produce a signal. Would this setup be able to track the paths and still produce interference pattern?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the "heavy particle" in your diagram?

Comment: @Floris: the slits are positioned upright and the source is at where you sit/stand so the screen is behind your phone/monitor.

Comment: So a source of heavy particles into the screen; if the particle goes through slit 1 or 2, it might interact with the laser passing along the length of the slit. What are you expecting to interfere with what? Sorry it's still unclear to me. Are you expecting interference between the laser beams detected by detectors 1 and 2? On the screen behind the monitor? Or...

Comment: @Floris:normally laser beam from source and splitter will recombine(cancel out each other), if a massive particle went through the slit it should distort the spacetime around it and so the laser beam will be ever so slightly bended and the new recombined signal can be detected. to your question, Both!

Comment: @Floris: the laser beam is not going to be exposed or get hit by the heavy particle throughout the experiment, I'm simply tracking the curvature of spacetime for each heavy particle(the really heavy ones) as they passes through the slits.

Comment: There is no conceptual difference between a bog-standard Michelson interferometer and a two slit experiment: both involve two discrete optical paths. In short you don't need to modify the device at all

Comment: @dmckee: I'm using heavy particles for double slit but the laser is just for detecting which slits did the heavy particle went through.